# is it Ok to make a jQuery Extension that depends on other jQuery Extension?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I think this is just a "**Best Practices"** question, but I was wondering if it is ok to make a jQuery extension that does not depend solely on jQuery, but also on another jQuery extension.

Thanks for your answers! =D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, many jquery plugins do this.

The main thing is that in the documentation you tell the user that they exist and that you follow the existing conventions regarding where you place the files.

This post may help as well:

[Guidelines for using jQuery plugins and their dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1263405/guidelines-for-using-jquery-plugins-and-their-dependencies)

Answer (score 6):

yes, of course. you should of couse point the user to the dependencies :-)

Comment: ...and/or provide the user with the dependencies, thus assuring them that they have the correct versions of everything to ensure compatibility.

Comment: +1!! But that will probably reduce the number of help msgs within your forum/blog by the half :-)

Answer (score 0):

As long as you make it **very clear** to the user that this is a requirement, I don't see any major issue with this.  The same is required with jQuery UI often.

Also, make getting your required extension as easy as possible.